# What problems result from servers not time-sync'd?

Tags: networking, active-directory, time-synchronization

What problems might arise within a domain when the member servers are not properly time-sync'd?  I'm aware that log entries are incorrect making troubleshooting more difficult in time-sensitive operations.  But would there be other symptoms, perhaps between file servers, authentication and certificate servers, would manifest themselves?

Comment: When you're talking about an AD domain: Kerberos tokens authentication tokens are only valid for 5 minutes IIRC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kerberos tickets granted for authentication are very time sensitive and the mechanism breaks down absent accurate time sync between clients, servers and ticket grantors.

Comment: We've definitely had problems with "no logon servers available" type of exceptions on those servers I've found were not synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

Many authentication protocols check for time skew.  Kerberos (AD Auth) being a notable one.

Comment: Don't forget time-based OTPs.